# Virtual Pageviews not showing up in Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I'm using Virtual Pageviews to track contentblocks on my one page website. I use the code below to tag the links. But there are no pageviews showing up in Google Analytics.

I want to use a virtual pageview in order to create a goal funnel in Google Analytics. That is not possible with a event.

What am I doing wrong?

```
<a href="http://www.test.nl/subscribe/test#2" onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/product_basic');">
```

The code on the page

```
<a class="btn btn-large" href="http://www.test.nl/subscribe/test-extra" onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/abonnement_extra');">Kies!</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/abonnement_extra') //wrong method
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/abonnement_extra']) //correct method
```

try this way ;)
and also be sure that you have provided the analytics account ID

Answer (score 3):

Probably the Google code has no time to fire before the href is honored and the user is directed away from the current page. User a timeout after the click event (so 100ms or so pass before the user is redirected) or rather implement the Google Tag Manager which has since a few days ago an integrated event listener tag that disposes with the need for inline scripting and related hacks.